# Вывод значений из БД Laravel

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно выводить названия, вот что у меня в `blade.php`

```
                @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
                    <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
```

Вот такую ошибку у меня выдает
**Property [guilds] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Вот что у меня в `Controller`

```
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $user = User::all();
        $guilds = Guild::all();
        $userGuild = UserGuild::all();

        return view('main.server.create', compact('user','guilds','userGuild'));
    }
```

Вот какая у меня связь в БД

**User**

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('guild_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('guild_id','user_guild_fk')->on('guilds')->references('id');
            $table->index('guild_id','user_guild_idx');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
```

**User_Guild**

```
        Schema::create('user_guilds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('guild_id')->nullable();

            $table->index('user_id','user_guild_user_idx');
            $table->index('guild_id','user_guild_guild_idx');

            $table->foreign('user_id','user_guild_user_fk')->on('users')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('guild_id','user_guild_guild_fk')->on('guilds')->references('id');

            $table->timestamps();
```

**Guild**

```
        Schema::create('guilds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Вы получили отдельно массив пользователей и гильдий (?), а пытаетесь вывести их через связь. Для начала - в $user у вас не один юзер, а коллекция, так что и перебирать нужно как коллекцию, в цикле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В модель User добавьте связь:

```
public function guilds()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Guild::class, 'user_guilds');
}
```

Тогда вы сможете получить список пользователей вместе с зависимыми моделями Guild:

```
$users = User::with('guilds')->get();
```

И уже после этого можно вывести все Guilds:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
    ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```